How to associate a user provided user assigned identity to one of the resources created by managed using ARM template
Is it possible to associate an existing(pre-created) user assigned identity to managed application(OR one of its resources(created by managed app) lets say a VM) so that this identity can then be used to assign rolemapping to an external resource(that it already has access on) on an identity thats created by managed application.
So far, I've tried  below:
--> Try to take a user identity from user and assign it to VM in the hopes to later use it for mapping with a script I run on the VM using AZ cli commands(logging in with the user passed identity).
I get below error:
The client 'XXXXX-XXX-XX-XXXXX-XXXXXXX' with object id 'XXXXX-XXX-XX-XXXXX-XXXXXXX' has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write' on scope '/subscriptions/YYYYYYYY-YYY-YYYY-bbcc-YYYYYYY/resourcegroups/magrp-mrg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/management-vm'; however, it does not have permission to perform action(s) 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/assign/action' on the linked scope(s) '/subscriptions/YYYYYYYY-YYY-YYYY-bbcc-YYYYYYY/resourceGroups/managedapp-sa/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/testidentity' (respectively) or the linked scope(s) are invalid. (Code: LinkedAuthorizationFailed)

--> Try to take a user identity from user assign it to deploymentScript (it spins up a temp VM probably to run mentioned az commands and in those az commands I basically try to do the role assignment on the identity created by managed application on an external resource to which the passed identity already has permissions on)
It fails as well
The Resource 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/testidentity' under resource group 'mapp-mrg' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix (Code: ResourceNotFound)
(This when i only passed identity reference)
Then I also additionally passed managed group where the passed identity lives and I get :
The client 'XXXXX-XXX-XX-XXXXX-XXXXXXX' with object id 'XXXXX-XXX-XX-XXXXX-XXXXXXX'  does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/read' over scope '/subscriptions/YYYYYYYY-YYY-YYYY-bbcc-YYYYYYY/resourceGroups/managedapp-sa/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/testidentity'  or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials. (Code: AuthorizationFailed)

I've also tried to follow this document -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/publish-managed-identity.
And I've been able to associate the external identity to managed app using createUiDefinition.json I just don't know how to associate this identity to one of the resources created by managed application? Since the document specifically asks not to use managedIdentity key within mainTemplate.json
Any suggestions how can this be achieved. Thanks in advance.
Edit:
Adding below image of the what the ask is to avoid any confusion(as it seems based on comments on the question)

Error with which Managed application fails


Are you looking out for only a VM resource or just opted VM as an example. @Cod_enthu

Do you want to associate an existing user-assigned managed identity with a VM and use this identity to assign role mappings to an external resource?

@VenkatV Yes correct, this MUI was already given necessary permissions to perform role mapping. Using this identity I'd like to assign this role mapping on an external resource to an identity created by managed application. The external resource in this case is a DNSZone, the MUI already has user access/owner privileges to this DNSZone, now using MUI I'd like to assign a DNSContributor role to an identity created by managed application.

@Jahnavi It can be a deploymentScript as well. The reason I'm thinking to associate this identity to VM(provisioned by MA), because then I also have an customExtensions(a script) running on this VM, where I was thinking to use AZ CLI commands to perform this assignment provided the identity gets added to VM. If there is any other/better solution I can try that as well?

Using user managed identity, you want to assign DNS contributor role to  DNSzone via  script (Azure CLI),but facing an error including MUI's has owner role.

@VenkatV Added a design image to clarify what the ask is.

How are you looking to manage this process—via script?

Via ARM template

The client 'XXXXX-XX' has does not have permission to perform action(s) 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/assign/action' on the linked scope(s) '/subscriptions/YYYYYYYY-YYY-YYYY-bbcc-YYYYYYY/resourceGroups/managedapp-sa/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/testidentity' (respectively) or the linked scope(s) are invalid. (Code: LinkedAuthorizationFailed)

The error you encountered is due to invalid permissions. Make sure to assign any of the roles below to the user to allow assigning an identity to the resource.
TheMicrosoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/assign/action permission is only available with the Contributor or Owner role.

Here is the ARM code to attach an existing User Assigned Managed Identity to a Virtual Machine and then assign a role to another resource using the same identity within a VM extension method.
VM.json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
        "apiVersion": "2024-03-01",
        "name": "myVNet",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
          "addressSpace": {
            "addressPrefixes": [
              "10.0.0.0/16"
            ]
          },
          "subnets": [
            {
              "name": "mySubnet",
              "properties": {
                "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
        "apiVersion": "2024-03-01",
        "name": "myPublicIP",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
          "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
        "apiVersion": "2024-03-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '-nic')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'myVNet')]",
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', 'myPublicIP')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "ipConfigurations": [
            {
              "name": "ipconfig1",
              "properties": {
                "subnet": {
                  "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'myVNet'), '/subnets/mySubnet')]"
                },
                "publicIPAddress": {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', 'myPublicIP')]"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        "apiVersion": "2023-03-01",
        "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "identity": {
          "type": "UserAssigned",
          "userAssignedIdentities": {
            "[parameters('userAssignedIdentityId')]": {}
          }
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat(parameters('vmName'), '-nic'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
          },
          "osProfile": {
            "computerName": "[parameters('vmName')]",
            "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
            "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
          },
          "storageProfile": {
            "imageReference": {
              "publisher": "[parameters('imagePublisher')]",
              "offer": "[parameters('imageOffer')]",
              "sku": "[parameters('imageSku')]",
              "version": "latest"
            },
            "osDisk": {
              "createOption": "FromImage",
              "managedDisk": {
                "storageAccountType": "StandardSSD_LRS"
              }
            }
          },
          "networkProfile": {
            "networkInterfaces": [
              {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat(parameters('vmName'), '-nic'))]"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
        "apiVersion": "2023-03-01",
        "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('vmName'), 'Roleassignment')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('vmName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
          "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
          "typeHandlerVersion": "1.7",
          "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
          "settings": {
            "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command \"', parameters('commands'), '\"')]"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "parameters": {
      "vmName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "myWindowsVM"
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
      },
      "vmSize": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Standard_DS1_v2"
      },
      "adminUsername": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "azureuser"
      },
      "adminPassword": {
        "type": "securestring",
        "defaultValue": "YourPassword123!"
      },
      "imagePublisher": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
      },
      "imageOffer": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "WindowsServer"
      },
      "imageSku": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "2022-Datacenter"
      },
      "userAssignedIdentityId": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/application-RG/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/Venkat-MUI"
      },
      "commands": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "az login --identity --username '<UAM client_id|object_id>'; az role assignment create --assignee 'UAM object_id' --role 'DNS Zone Contributor' --scope '/subscriptions/8332bf56-xxxxxxxxx-a507-d7e60e5f09a9/resourceGroups/application-RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/contoso.com'"
      }
    }
  }
 

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name "venkat" -ResourceGroupName "application-RG" -TemplateFile .\VM.json

After running the ARM code, a VM resource has been created, and a role has been assigned to the Private DNS from the VM using the extension method with CLI commands.
Output:
VM Creation:

UAM Assignment in VM

Role assignment

Reference:   Deploy virtual machine extensions with ARM templates

Are you able to resolve now or still facing an issue?

Thanks for attempting this, I'd tried this in the exact same way but I get the error I mentioned earlier. The identity that I pass(as part of installation wizard of managed application) to be associated with the VM is present in a group A. When I create a managed application, it deploys resources as part of group lets say B. In this group B as part of the managed application deployment, the VM is created, an identity is created and so on etc.

What I intend to do is to assign the external identity from group A to the VM that gets created by the MA so that I can perform the operations as you listed in the commands.
But irrespective of what rolemapping I do on the DNSZone(assign owner permission to the existing MUI) prior to the run, I still get the same error I mentioned earlier and the managed application deployment fails

Sometimes, it may take time to apply the role. The Owner role is sufficient to assign roles.

Updated the post with the managed application failure message

When you attempting to associate the external identity from Group A to a VM in Group B, the managed identity in Group B likely lacks the Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/read or assign permissions over the identity in Group A

Yes that probably is the cause, this managedIdentity in Group B or the group created by managed application has its own identity that's used by the managed application to do the deployment operations which is what is probably lacking the permission to do what needs to be done, and I'm not sure how to resolve that.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

With all the tests, so far it appears that a managed application's created resource(VM in this case) can't receive an external MUI to associate with it, no matter what permissions one maps to this MUI(tried resource groups, subscription level etc).
